# Keyboard layout wrong on Arch Linux emergency mode

Tags: keyboard, shell, arch-linux, layout, spanish

If on Arch Linux emergency mode:

```
systemd.unit=emergency.target
```

I change US keyboard layout to Spanish:

```
# loadkeys es
```

special characters fail.

For example: if I type "**ñ**" shell shows "**A±**". If I type "**¿**" shell shows "**A¿**". If I type "**ç**" shell shows "**A∮**".

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED.

In **Emergency Mode** or **Normal Mode**:

- Edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment `#es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8`:

`# nano /etc/locale.gen`

Before:

`#es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8`

After:

`es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8`

- Generate the locales:

`# locale-gen`

- Add LANG variable:

`# echo LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 > /etc/locale.conf`

- Define keyboard layout:

`# echo KEYMAP=es > /etc/vconsole.conf`

- Edit `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` file and move `keyboard` word **before** `autodetect` word in HOOK parameters:

`# nano /etc/mkinitcpio.conf`

Before:

`HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf kms keyboard keymap consolefont block encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)`

After:

`HOOKS=(base udev keyboard autodetect modconf kms keymap consolefont block encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck)`

- Regenerate **initramfs** image:

`# mkinitcpio -p linux`

- Reboot system and return to Emergency Mode

Now Emergency, Recovery and Rescue Modes have Spanish keyboard by default correctly without errors in special characters.